# One word to describe a place's quality of being a prospect to revisits

Tags: adjectives

Can anyone tell me if there's one word to describe a place's quality which gravitates people into revisiting it in the future? It's not quite attractiveness though, but rather something more specific. I suppose the equivalent of *replay value* (as with video games).

If this is going to help, I'll be using the word in a feedback form, wherein one criterion is to measure the guest's willingness to return. It should also be ratable by high or low.

Edit. I would be using "*revisitability*" if only it is a word. (Haha.) It's the closest to what I need.

Comment: *Ambience*? *Atmosphere*? *Picturesqueness*? *Quaintness*? *Beauty*?

Comment: Sorry. I thought that you meant a physical location, not an Internet site. I should have read your second paragraph. How about *usability*?

Comment: No, not really. The word I'm looking for is a result of everything in the place which encourages a second visit.

Comment: I would just ask them how likely they are to use the site again. After all, that's what you want to find out. If you ask them how attractive or how friendly the site is, you are asking them to form an opinion that may be entirely irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! But now that I've already been put to looking for that word, I don't want to stop until I find it. It has bugging me a lot, personally more than for the feedback form itself.

Comment: Ah! You're on a quest.

Comment: The Asker appears to me to refer to using an internet site to comment on a geographical place - am I right?

Comment: Yeah. Even the people I asked about it began their own hunts.
Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Kate Bunting: It's a physical questionnaire. Although, there's really no difference from how you see it except that.

Comment: if I was filling ina form that asked me to rate 'revisitability' my partner would have to wrest the form from me to stop me giving a detailed critique of how irritating poorly worded questions are. Assume of your visitors that not all have English as a first language and people have varying degrees of literacy. Use plain English, use simple constructions. If asking 'Are you likely to revisit?' isn't enough info, ask questions that explore whether they feel they saw all there was to see, if there are particular things they want to do again...

Comment: Not the "quality" of the website per se, but you could use the term **retention rate** to denote the ratio of people who visited your website more than once over all the people who visited it.

Comment: -1.  This is an obvious case a few plain simple words prevails over a singular contrived terminology.

Comment: Paolo's Italian Kitchen is unfortunately closed so please consider [“Revisit worthy?”](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g186562-d4467319-r203985241-Paolo_s_Italian_Kitchen-Airdrie_North_Lanarkshire_Scotland.html) with that in mind, but maybe if the reviewer had hyphenated it, more people would have taken it seriously and Paolo's delicious Sea Bass would still be available! (or maybe ["habit-forming?"](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g42404-d10455125-r402576409-Country_House_Ice_Cream_LLC-Lewiston_Michigan.html)?)

Comment: I still want to know whether there's a single word for it. It has become a personal matter now, instead of for the sake of the questionnaire.

Answer (score 2):

***Draw***

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/draw):

> something that attracts customers, an audience, etc.

Example: He found the draw of sandy beaches irresistible.

Comment: I added the link to your citation and put the definition in block quotes. +1

Answer (score 0):

***irresistible***, from the [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/irresistible)

> impossible to refuse, oppose, or avoid because too pleasant, 
>   attractive, or strong:
>
> Example
>
> I wasn’t going to have dessert, but the pie proved irresistible

In your case:

> I thought I had gotten everything I could from one visit, but the site
>   was irresistible.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably referring to the ***allure*** of a place. *Allure* is the quality of a place which attracts people to visit it (first time based on hearsay and repeat visits based on personal experience).

Urban Dictionary:

> **[allure](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=allure)**
>
> appeal or attraction to somthing. you can't get enough of it
>
> Jay-z said it best, “The allure of the game keeps calling my name"
>   that’s why he stays rapping even after retirement he’s in love and
>   drawn into the rap game

M-W:

> **[allure](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allure)**
>   *noun*
>
> :  power of attraction or fascination:  charm
>
> the nostalgic allure of America's Wild West still attracts vacationers
>   to ghost towns

Also, ***charm*** may work, though I feel *allure* works better on a feedback form.

M-W:

> **[charm](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charm)**
>   *noun*
>
> **3c** :  compelling attractiveness : the island possessed great charm

Answer (score 0):

You might say that the place has *staying power*, meaning that (in this context) it continues to demand visits from you after you have already visited.

The phrase generally refers to the ability to continue in some state without weakening. It would be non-standard to use it here but the meaning would be readily understood.

Comment: The place should here have `power to make 'em come back`, not `staying power` which BTW makes sense only for the _visitor_ to have.